# Bootstrap alert angular service

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to setup an alert service in my angular app and I'm running into some trouble. Here's some code -

app.js

```
'use strict';

var developerPortalApp = angular.module('developerPortalApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ]).factory('alertService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var alertService;
  $rootScope.alerts = [];
  return alertService = {
    add: function(type, msg) {
      return $rootScope.alerts.push({
        type: type,
        msg: msg,
        close: function() {
          return alertService.closeAlert(this);
        }
      });
    },
    closeAlert: function(alert) {
      return this.closeAlertIdx($rootScope.alerts.indexOf(alert));
    },
    closeAlertIdx: function(index) {
      return $rootScope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    },
    clear: function(){
      $rootScope.alerts = [];
    }
  };
}]);
```

And here is some controller code I'm using to push an alert, note that 'alertService' is included in this controller

```
// Update user information
    $scope.userUpdate = function (user) {
      /*jshint unused: false */
      $http.put('api/users/v1/' + $cookies.id, {
        'email': user.email,
        'username': user.email,
        'scope': 'User',
        'source': 'external',
        'lastName': user.lastName,
        'firstName': user.firstName
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alertService.add('success', 'Your account information has been successfully updated');
      }).error(
        function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('error!');
          alertService.add('danger', 'There was a problem updating your account');
        });
    };
```

And finally, here is the HTML in the view

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}"close="closeAlert($index)">{{ alert.msg }}</alert>
```

This was working fine before I tried to put things into a service (had a $scope.alerts[] in each controller).

Anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post also the code of your `alert` directive?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace '$rootScope.alerts' with '$scope.alerts'. For any refrence [click here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert).

Comment: `rootScope` allows binding outside of Controller directives. That is not the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Please try close="alert.close()" in your HTML directive

Comment: please explain how it will work or just add comment for such solution.

Comment: The author has redefine alerts close function in the the following code   "return $rootScope.alerts.push({
        type: type,
        msg: msg,
        close: function() {
          return alertService.closeAlert(this);
        }
      });